# Validate parsed data in django admin

Tags: python, django, validation

I am new in Django. I want to do a duplicate validation check on a parsed data from uploaded xml file in Django admin.

1. The admin uploads the xml file
2. Extract the required data
3. Validate if the data is already exist in the database
4. If yes raise validationError
5. If no then save the model.

The above points are working except point 3. I am not sure where in `admin.py` should I check if the value already exists or not.

Code from `admin.py`

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not change:
            category_name, module_names = \
                self.handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['category_file'])
 .......................................................................

def handle_uploaded_file(self, f):
#Upload the file
..................................
    return self.parse_uploaded_xml(name)

def parse_uploaded_xml(self, name):        
    tree = ET.parse(name)
    root = tree.getroot()

    category_name = root[0].text
    ..............................
    #return the category name and module name
```

Code from models.py

```
category_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False, null=True, default="", unique=True)
module_name = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
```

I want to use the following code for the validation

```
def clean_category_name(self):
        if self.category_name and Category.objects.filter(category_name=self.category_name).exists():
            raise ValidationError('This category is already in the database. Please supply a different category.')
```

`unique = true` doesn't work while uploading the file/adding a category but it works when I edit a single category.

Any help/link/suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.